# direct routing to TYPO3 extension files

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I am a maintainer of the TYPO3 extension QFQ.

Our extension accesses many of its files directly by links relative to `index.php` of TYPO3. For example it requests the following API file via JavaScript in the frontend:

```
/typo3conf/ext/qfq/Classes/Api/file.php
```

Since the upgrade to spoken URLs with TYPO3 v9 these relative paths stopped working. For example the above relative path would result in the following url when clicked on in the browser:

```
example.com/en/.../typo3conf/ext/qfq/Classes/Api/file.php
```

instead of:

```
example.com/typo3conf/ext/qfq/Classes/Api/file.php
```

We have seen that one can add static routes to single files in the TYPO3 backend (Sites > Edit > Static Routes > Create new) but this does not seem to allow us to set the whole extension directory `/typo3conf/ext/qfq` as a static route. Since many files are accessed this way, it is way too tedious to set a static route for every single fie on every installation of TYPO3 which uses our extension.

Our own "dirty" solution to this problem would be to add a new rewrite rule to the .htaccess which rewrites any url containing `typo3conf/ext/qfq`. It would remove any path before typo3conf.

My question is: Is there a better way to solve this problem? How do other extensions create links directly pointing to the files inside the extension directory? Are we missing something obvious?

Comment: Common approach in TYPO3 is handling such requests via controller's context and I'd definitely suggest to refactor this instead of accessing files directly. Anyway if for some reason you still want to use *standalone* scripts, you can just move file in the file structure to some other folder like `domain.tld/api/file.php` and/or use htaccess to shortcut the URL

Comment: It's not recommended to access PHP files inside your extension directly. Use a controller or the Middleware to handle such calls. In a secured environment the direct access to PHP files inside extensions folder is restricted and your extension won't work.

Comment: I think your problem is that you skipped the link generation of TYPO3 and build up the URLs in the rendering by hand. As your implementation depends on the old TYPO3 behaviour of running as `/index.php` your URLs have the wrong path. It looks like you use relative paths where changing to absolute paths should be enough. Please give some examples how you render the usage of your files. maybe it is enough to use some URL ViewHelper.

Comment: @biesior Going through TYPO3 just to call our simple API scripts seems like an unneccessary addition of complexity in our case. Besides that, the extension also loads some icons from the extension directory. Would you also access those via TYPO3? To be honest I never really went deeply into the TYPO3 API, it might be more staight forward than it seems to me. Can you maybe point me to an example which solves this particular problem via a controllers context?

Comment: I understand your needs, but if you decided not to use TYPO3 for some parts of your code (like API) you also don't need to keep it in `typo3conf/ext/yourexr/Classes` folder. It's not popular for developing in TYPO3 like this but in such a case I just would move this code to the `api` folder and I'm pretty sure it won't conflict with TYPO3's file structure. Another possibility is creating a micro-service in a subdomain and there you can use raw PHP for the whole subproject just to create an API.